# Google Chrome - Using OpenGL as the ANGLE Backend Sometimes Makes Webpage Elements Disappear and Reappear - Anyone else?

Tags: google-chrome, opengl

In the Google Chrome web browser, I've been using OpenGL as the backend for ANGLE (set using the `chrome://flags/#use-angle` flag) for some time now because I find that YouTube videos look better with it. But recently I've noticed that some website's elements will disappear and reappear. Sometimes it's just buttons on a page, or a banner at the top, other times it's the background of a page, and sometimes nothing breaks. Scrolling or clicking around bring the elements back but they usually disappear again at random. I haven't been able to pinpoint if it's a specific thing causing it. I just know that if I put the ANGLE backend back to default it stops so it definitely seems like an OpenGL thing.

It didn't used to be like this so maybe a Chrome update messed with something? I've tried updating my Nvidia drivers and that didn't fix it. I can replicate it on other computers so it's not something localized to this one. Has anyone else experienced this?